# How to solve " Notice: Use of undefined constant HOST - assumed 'HOST' in C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon-ac\kk_inc\db_connect.php on line 3 "

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I define constant in config.php and include_once in db_connect.php and then i include db_connect.phph in databases.php function file to use all function in all pages like in login.php

my codes are as bellow  :

login.php header code -

```
 <?php

include_once 'kk_inc/database.php';

sec_session_start();

?>
```

in database.php i nclude db_connect.php

db_connect.php code -

```
    <?php
include_once 'config.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE) or die(mysql_error("database not connected")) ;

?>
```

and my config.php code -

```
<?php
/**
 * These are the database login details
 */  
define("HOST", "localhost");     // The host you want to connect to.
define("USER", "root");    // The database username. 
define("PASSWORD", "");    // The database password. 
define("DATABASE", "kkdb_ac01");    // The database name.

define("CAN_REGISTER", "any");
define("DEFAULT_ROLE", "member");

define("SECURE", FALSE);    // FOR DEVELOPMENT ONLY!!!!

?>
```

Getting error when i run login.php file as like bellow :

> Notice: Use of undefined constant HOST - assumed 'HOST' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon-ac\kk_inc\db_connect.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant USER - assumed 'USER' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon-ac\kk_inc\db_connect.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant PASSWORD - assumed 'PASSWORD' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon-ac\kk_inc\db_connect.php on line 3
>
> Notice: Use of undefined constant DATABASE - assumed 'DATABASE' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon-ac\kk_inc\db_connect.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon-ac\kk_inc\db_connect.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\amazon-ac\kk_inc\db_connect.php on line 3

Help me to idetify exact what happens in this,Please .

Comment: Change the include to require and see if it errors.

Comment: Yes it's error same " mr.john " ,and " Mr. Your Common Sense " want to ask to you that it's compalcary to include config.php at all page as per you suggest me that duplicate one